# Convert EPSG:32632 coordinates in meters in JAVA

Tags: java, epsg

I'm trying to find a solution to convert my epsg:32632 coordinates into meters.
epsg:32632 coordinates look like: 13.39453125, 58.34765625.

Does anyone know how can i do this in java?

Thanks,

Ares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to look at one of the geo toolkits out there.  GeoTools (geotools.org) may have something to do this.  What you're going to need to do is create a line geometry in the SRID you have above, then convert it to another SRID that more or less matches your spheroid etc but has a unit of meters.